# Kafka rolling restart: Data is lost

Tags: apache-kafka, high-availability

As part of our current Kafka cluster, high-availability testing (HA) is being done. The objective is, while a producer job is pushing data to a particular partition of a topic, all the brokers in Kafka cluster are restarted sequentially (Stop-first broker- restart it and after first broker comes up, do same steps for second broker and so-on). The producer job is pushing around 7 million records for about 30 minutes while this test is going on. At the end of job, it was noticed that around 1000 records are missing.

**Below are specifics of our Kafka cluster: (kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0)**

-3 Kafka brokers each with 2 100GB mounts

**Topic was created with:**
-Replication factor of 3
-min.insync.replica=2

**server.properties:**

```
broker.id=1
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=1048576
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=1048576
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/drive1,/drive2
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.flush.interval.messages=10000
log.retention.hours=1
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=1800000
log.cleaner.enable=false
zookeeper.connect=ZK1:2181,ZK2:2181,ZK3:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=10000
advertised.host.name=XXXX
auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true
auto.create.topics.enable=false
queued.max.requests=500
delete.topic.enable=true
controlled.shutdown.enable=true
unclean.leader.election=false
num.replica.fetchers=4
controller.message.queue.size=10
```

**Producer.properties (aync producer with new producer API)**

```
bootstrap.servers=broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092
acks=all
buffer.memory=33554432
compression.type=snappy
batch.size=32768
linger.ms=5
max.request.size=1048576
block.on.buffer.full=true
reconnect.backoff.ms=10
retry.backoff.ms=100
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

Can someone share any info about Kafka-cluster and HA to ensure that data would not be lost while rolling restarting Kafka brokers?

Also, here is my producer code. This is a fire and forget kind of producer. we are not handling failures explicitly as of now. Working fine for almost millions of records. I am seeing problem, only when Kafka brokers are restarted as explained above.

```
public void sendMessage(List<byte[]> messages, String destination, Integer parition, String kafkaDBKey) {

    for(byte[] message : messages) {

        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>(destination, parition, kafkaDBKey.getBytes(), message));

    }

}
```

Comment: How long did you run the test in total?
Could it be that some messages were deleted because of retention? `log.retention.check` is set to 30min and `log.retention.hours` to 1h.

Comment: I ran job for 30 minutes. Retention period is for about 4 hours. I don't see any data is being removed. I confirmed this by verifying  earliest and latest offsets of that partition.

Comment: How does your producer handle failures ? Would posting its code be possible?

Comment: Thanks Doomy. I added code above. This is asynchronous call to broker. Not handling any explicit failures as of now. We have requirement of maintaining sequence of records also on consumer side. Any suggestions to improve the above code to maintain order and not loosing records?

Answer (score 2):

By increasing default retries value from 0 to 4000 on producer side, we are able to send data successfully without loosing.
**`retries=4000`**

- Due to this setting, there is a possibility of sending same message twice and messages are out of sequence by the time consumer receives it (second msg might reach before first msg). But for our current problem that is not an issue and is handled on consumer side to ensure everything is in order.